# Is it okay to use partially used label sheets in laser printers?

Tags: printing, printer

If you print a few labels on a label sheet, say, address labels, is it okay to then reuse that sheet in a laser printer to print more labels at some later date? I've always considered the risk of a label peeling off the sheet and then getting stuck inside the laser printer too risky and not worth the cost of the printer, but I wonder if I'm just being too cautious and wasting sheets.

Comment: Is it worth the risk? Only you can decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of factors that affect success and risks.

**The label stock**

- How well the labels are separated from each other.  If the label outline is cleanly precut all the way around the label all the way to the backing paper, pulling off the previous labels will be less likely to tug on edges of the remaining labels and loosen them.  On the other hand, labels that are slightly attached to each other reduces the chance of a stray label being peeled off in the printer.
- How well the labels are adhered to the backing.  Labels that are strongly adhered to the backing paper will be less likely to peel off in the printer.
- How old the labels are and how many times they've been through the printer.  The label adhesive dries out with age and with passes through the printer.  So even good labels that were well-adhered to the backing paper can lose that adhesion and come off in the printer.  You'll have better luck reusing fresh labels and limiting passes to no more than a few times.

**Previous printing**

- The pattern of remaining labels.  Full rows vs. partial rows may affect the tendency for labels to peel off in the printer.  The amount and location of exposed backing paper can affect how well the paper feed rollers move the sheet.  The best results would come from printing one pass, then turn the sheet around and print from the other edge (assuming the sheets are symmetrical).  Then if there are still labels left on the sheet, find another use for them.  Plan your label printing to take advantage large batches rather than printing a few labels at a time.

**Printer**

- Paper Handling.  Some printers do a better job of feeding challenging paper than others.  Some have more bends in the paper path.  A printer with more bends or sharper bends is more likely to peel off marginally adhered labels inside the printer.
- Serviceability.  Some printers have very accessible paper paths.  If a label peels off inside, you can get at it to remove it.  Others not so much, and a label stuck inside may require a service call.  That will be much more expensive than the value of a fractional sheet of labels.

So you need to weigh the factors that apply in your case.  If you do reuse label sheets, minimize the risks as described above.

Another option to consider is a dedicated label printer.  Relatively inexpensive printers are available.  But like razor blades and inkjet printer ink, the companies make their money on over-priced supplies (there are some third-party label manufacturers that offer good quality at a much lower price).  You don't need to use that for all your labels, just the odds and ends that would waste a sheet of laser printer labels.  A few label printer labels will be cheaper than a wasted half sheet of laser labels.

Comment: Very thorough answer. My printer has a built-in duplexer so it has no straight-through paper path, and I do have a Brother labeler. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this a number of times on different laser printers. In  general it works well. The only problem was with older printers (>20 years), which used oiled fusers. In these printers, the oil accumulated on the labels so that, after a few passes, the toner would no longer adhere properly. Instead it would stay on the fuser and deposited on subsequent pages.

I always used decent quality labels, and the labels always stayed on the backing sheet. If they do come of, they will only cause bad problems if they get stuck inside the fuser, as they may be hard to remove without damaging the fuser. Of course, the fuser is a consumable and not too expensive to replace ;-) If the label gets stuck anywhere else, removing it should not be that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this depends entirely on your printer and your luck. It should work; I have done this with my own printer without any issues. It all comes down to, are you comfortable tearing apart your printer and fixing it if it doesn't work?